# How to stop executing else block while searching in an array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

Here's the code part :-

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and say I want to search 5 and print it's index.

```
x=Number to be searched 
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if x==arr[i]:
        print("Found at",i)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

The output is as follows :-

```
Found at 4
Found at 10
Not found
```

Hoe to get rid of the last line ? It should not be printed as 5 is present in arr! 
Note : I just started learning python few days ago so I'm sorry if this is a trivial question but I can't get the reason of it printing that one.

Comment: So you don't seem to need the `else` part then.

Comment: Ah, I see that I changed your indentation when fixing your code for proper formatting. The `else:` branch of a `for` loop is executed when you reach the end. You can *stop* the `else` branch from executing by using `break`.  But you *can't break out of the loop here*. Don't use `else:`, use a flag variable or counter.

Comment: What if someone searched an item not present in the array? It should handle some error message .

Comment: @Epsilonzero set a flag that you set to True when you stuble upon the desired number. Then in a condition outside of the main for loop, if the flag is False, then print your "Not found" message.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `else:` here, because `for:...else:` executes the `else` branch *when you reach the end of the loop*. You can only prevent this by using `break` in the `for` loop so it doesn't reach the end. You can`t use`break` here because you want to show *all* matching values.

You have two options:

- Use a flag variable to remember that you found matches; set it to `True` when you have a match:

  ```
  found = False  # flag variable, defaulting to 'nothing found'
  for i in range(len(arr)):
      if x==arr[i]:
          print("Found at", i)
          found = True  # found at least one match, set the flag to true
  if not found:
      print("Not found")
  ```
- Gather all indices into a list *first*, before printing. If the list is empty, you know didn't find anything:

  ```
  indices = []
  for i in range(len(arr)):
      if x==arr[i]:
          indices.append(i)

  if indices:
      for index in indices:
          print('Found at:', index)
  else:
      print("Not found")
  ```

That last option can be achieved more concisely with a single list comprehension and the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
indices = [i for i, value in enumerate(arr) if value == x]
if indices:
    for index in indices:
        print("Found at", index)
else:
    print("Not found")
```